# Compare two columns contain the same value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have below data.

```
Declare @mytable TABLE(EmpName varchar(100),MATHS INT,SCIENCE INT)
INSERT INTO @mytable 
VALUES('Ram',50,60)
,('Krishna',100,30)
,('Ramesh',90,90)
```

I want to show the records which meets the condition (Maths=90 and Science=90).

I wrote the below query.

```
SELECT EmpName
,CASE WHEN MATHS=90 THEN CASE WHEN SCIENCE =90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END
 FROM @mytable
```

Any other way to re write the above query.

Appreciate your help.

Thank You

Comment: `Select empname from @mytable where science=90 and maths=90` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL's **Inline If**. Looking at code you want to return whether these people have scored 90 in both exams and flag them as such in a single column by returning 1 if they meet the criteria and 0 if they do not.

In this instance from a readability perspective I would choose inline if over the **Case** keyword.

```
SELECT  EmpName,
        IIF((MATHS = 90 AND SCIENCE = 90), 1, 0)
FROM @mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write

```
CASE WHEN MATHS = 90 AND MATHS = SCIENCE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```